# Microsoft Word, USB Data

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-word

When doing the following:

- Open a blank word document
- Plug-in an USB drive containing a Word file
- Insert the content of the Word file on the USB drive through Insert->Object->"Text from file"
- Don't save the document, but just view it, and close it.
- Remove the USB drive.

Can someone access the contents of the file that was loaded from the USB drive? It doesn't show up on recent documents, but when I enter the name of that file in the window menu search bar it does.

Comment: Well, why don't you try it then? After you pull the device out, and click on the recent documents item, what happens? I also believe the MS suite uses autosave which you may want to look into

Comment: The only way I can see it might is if Word crashes while you're looking.  It will then be available in the recovery section, depending on the version of Word.

Comment: It weird cause the Microsoft Word program when open and actually  when checking recent it doesn't say the file name, that was used, but if you go into the search bar for the window menu and search for it, t shows up but when you click it, its says "the device or network connection that the shortcut"______*file name____________"  checklist.ink refers i unavailable. Make sure that the dis properly inserted or the network resource is available and then try again"

Comment: Given that^ can someone still access the file, anyways yes or no? Ok suppose I don't wanna face that situation and I instead, did the method above BUT i copied all the contents that was on the blank file with the "Text from file", closed the window without saving, inject my usb out and open a brand new document and pasted it onto there, just for viewing purpose, would the someone be track be able find exactly what was copied?

Answer (score 1):

As you explained, the name of the file is recorded, but the contents of the file will not be available as long as you keep the USB flash drive away from the computer.

If you are using Microsoft Office 2013 and later, and the unsaved file that you explained had been open for a very long time, consider seeing the following folder, as it might contain fragments of the unsaved file which you closed:

> `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`

Feel free to delete anything you found there.