# How can I fix the multiple Word docs that I cannot open on my external SSD hard drive?

Tags: microsoft-word, ssd, file-corruption

I have most of my Word and other docs stored on an external SSD drive.  Numerous, but not all Word documents are unable to be loaded.  When I try the message is as follows: "Word found unreadable content in 'name of word document'.  Do you want to recover the contents of this document?  If you trust the source of this document, click yes."

When I click yes, this message, "Word experienced an error trying to open the file.  Try these suggestions>  *Check the file permissions for the document or drive.  *Make sure there is sufficient free memory and disk space.  *Open the file with the Text Recovery converter."

I have checked and repaired the disk several times.  No change.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: This appears to be a common problem with MS Word: see https://superuser.com/questions/1156022/microsoft-word-usb-data , for example. It could be that the drive was removed before Word actually wrote the contents of the file to the drive. What is the size of the files? If zero or just a few bytes, they're just placeholders with no data. Examine the files in a hex editor to see if there is any data at all.

Comment: Removed [tag:google-docs] because this file format can't be saved locally, when using Google Drive for Desktop, it will save shortcuts.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://superuser.com/a/1752339/705502